# Installing java 11 and getting java 10

Tags: apt, java

I've installed in Ubuntu bionic the following package in a 64 bits system:

```
apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Now I try the new java:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

The question is why I'm getting Java 10 instead of 11.

With this command, I see that no other java is installed in my system:

```
# update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install OpenJDK 11, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Source:[1](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-11-on-ubuntu-1804-for-real) is an explanation of the confusing name of the package.

> The Ubuntu Foundation Team made an SRU exception for OpenJDK. Although
>   version 10 is a non-LTS release, they've packaged it as openjdk-11-jdk
>   until OpenJDK 11 goes GA. This choice was based on that assumption
>   that there is a much smaller interface delta between releases 10 and
>   11 than it would be between 8 and 11.
>
> That's a fairly good reasoning and perhaps an apt-get upgrade wouldn't
>   screw things up that badly when OpenJDK's version gets bumped up from
>   10 to 11.